# Making a symbolic function callable -- sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I'd like to calculate the derivative, then solve for when it is zero.

I am using the sympy module to do this.

```
r = somefunction(x1,x2)
```

Using this function, I'd like to be able to call these two matrices.

```
r_grad = [r.diff(x1), r.diff(x2)]
r_hess = [[r.diff(x1,x1), r.diff(x1,x2)],[r.diff(x2,x1), r.diff(x2,x2)]]
```

I'd then like to solve for when r_grad[0] and r_grad[1] == 0, and plug that into the hessian. 
How can I make these .diff() symbols callable?

Comment: Did you attempt to find a solution before coming here? Googling "SymPy evaluate expression" turns up multiple ways to do this in the official documentation as the first few hits.

Comment: @user2357112 I did attempt to find a solution but I wasn't googling the right phrase. Now that I looked at what you suggested, I see it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SymPy has a [lambdify](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) module for these purposes:

```
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

func = lambdify((x1, x2), r.diff(x1))

func(1, 2) # evaluate the function efficiently at (1, 2)
```